How can Kotlin fail to find a value in a LinkedHashMap when one of the keys returns true for equals?
I have a secondaryOutputProperties map,
 private val secondaryOutputProperties = mutableMapOf<URI, MutableMap<QName, XdmValue>>()

And I have a uri: URI that actually comes from the keys of another map.
I'm getting an inexplicable NPE. Consider this code:
            for ((puri, _) in secondaryOutputProperties) {
                println("Map URI: $puri, ${puri.equals(uri)}")
            }
            println("Key URI: $uri")
            val x = secondaryOutputProperties[uri]
            println("s[uri] = ${x}")
            val y = secondaryOutputProperties.get(uri)
            println("s.get(uri) = ${y}")
            println("in? ${uri in secondaryOutputProperties}")
            println("conains? ${secondaryOutputProperties.containsKey(uri)}")

The output is:
Map URI: file:/Volumes/Projects/xproc/test-suite/test-suite/tests/secondary-false, true
Map URI: file:/Volumes/Projects/xproc/test-suite/test-suite/tests/secondary-true, false
Key URI: file:/Volumes/Projects/xproc/test-suite/test-suite/tests/secondary-false
s[uri] = null
s.get(uri) = null
in? false
conains? false

The next statement in the method is:
            val serprops = secondaryOutputProperties[uri]!!

And that throws an NPE.
This is a single threaded program, so there's no other thread removing keys from the map or anything like that. How can puri.equals(uri) return true, but get() fail to find the value?
I assume I'm overlooking something obvious, but I don't see it...

I realized I had no idea what version of Kotlin this is. It's 2.0.21.

It's probably also worth observing that the test does not fail consistently. If I run the test several times, the values are always "the same" but sometimes the keys are "in" the map and sometimes they aren't.

When they compare equal, the hashCode() values are also the same.

Just to be extra clear, URI means java.net.URI, right?

Try to create a reproducible example. Such behavior is definitely not expected and I would assume problem is somewhere else. Either in the implementation of the URI class (hashCode/equals) or this is not a standard LinkedHashMap (but you said you use mutableMapOf) or there are other threads (but you said it is single-threaded). There must be another explanation.

Agree with other comment that a minimal reproducible example is needed here. It would also be helpful to know what JVM you're using, since java.net.URI is supposed to be immutable. I know you say it is a single threaded program, but the fact that your test does not fail consistently certainly makes it seem that there is a race condition somewhere. I wonder if you could still replicate this issue, if you were to rewrite your code so that secondaryOutputProperties was immutable

It's in a big application, and smells very strongly of side effects, so I have extremely low expectations that I'd succeed in reproducing it in a smaller example. But I suppose I'll have to try. Yes, it's a jave.net.URI. The secondaryOutputProperties map is mutable because it's constructed during execution. I don't think it'd be practical to make immutable.

I switched from URI keys to String keys and managed to get different hashCode()s for two apparently identical strings. And then I got a LinkedHashMap with a size of 1 containing 2 entries. And secondaryOutputProperty.keys throws an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. Something is very wrong here.

It was a multithreading bug. #blush
My code: single thread. Third party library: not so much.
Apologies for the noise.
